# I want custom UI same ticket with dashline

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm having an UI like this one.

But I don't want the background behind to be an image because when I meet a phone with a larger screen it will be jagged edges and not smooth.

[image: Flutter ticket UI]

Comment: a SVG may be???

Comment: with SVG you can't correct position of view two sides dashline.

Answer (score 1):

I have customized it in the following way and it looks really good:

Create `TicketClipper` class extends CustomClipper.

```
class TicketClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {


@override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();

    path.lineTo(size.width*3/4, 0.0);
    path.relativeArcToPoint(const Offset(20, 0),
        radius: const Radius.circular(10.0), largeArc: true, clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(size.width-10, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0.0, size.width, 10.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height -10 );
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width, size.height, size.width-10, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width*3/4+20, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset((size.width*3/4), size.height),
        radius: const Radius.circular(10.0), clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(10.0, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, size.height, 0.0, size.height - 10);
    path.lineTo(0.0, 10.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Next, create a `BorderPainter` file to draw border:

```
class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0
      ..color = Colors.grey[300];
    Path path = Path();
//    uncomment this and will get the border for all lines
    path.lineTo(size.width*3/4, 0.0);
    path.relativeArcToPoint(const Offset(20, 0),
        radius: const Radius.circular(10.0), largeArc: true, clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(size.width-10, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0.0, size.width, 10.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height -10 );
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width, size.height, size.width-10, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width*3/4+20, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset((size.width*3/4), size.height),
        radius: const Radius.circular(10.0), clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(10.0, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, size.height, 0.0, size.height - 10);
    path.lineTo(0.0, 10.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Finally use:

```
PhysicalShape(
    color: Colors.white,
    elevation: 4,
    shadowColor: Color(0xFFE4E4E4).withOpacity(0.5),
    clipper: TicketClipper(),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ClipPath(
          clipper: TicketClipper(),
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          ),
        ),
        CustomPaint(
          painter: BorderPainter(),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: width,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Results will be displayed when running:

[image]

Comment: no need for a custom `CustomClipper` and custom `CustomPainter` - all you need is a custom `ShapeBorder` - this is a flutter way - check how other shapes are made like `RoundedRectangleBorder`, `CircleBorder` etc

Comment: This can make the position drop shadow not correct with above UI.

Comment: check `ShapeDecoration` where you can define any shadow you want

Comment: Can you help me this UI https://stackoverflow.com/q/64871992/9405238

Comment: `CustomPainter` definitely

Comment: I have built backend face recognition with Python, but I don't know how to capture image from live camera and send to server.

Comment: there are plugins for camera and http uploads on https://pub.dev/

Comment: I want it to show the front camera and show a green frame around the realtime face, if it does not work